# RRD tool retrieve maximum value

Tags: rrdtool, cacti

am trying to get the speed and maximum values for all of my interface using rrdtool using rrdtool fetch ... etc but the max value is for the standard time

ex :

rrdtool fetch xxx.rrd MAX -r 7200 -s 1357041600 -e now

i just need to get the highest maximum value for 1 year

Answer (score 0):

Use rrdtool graph VDEF and PRINT without giving any actual graphing commands. This will return the number you are looking for.

Comment: Can you gimme me an example ? as i need to export values on excel sheet

Comment: something like this ```VDEF:max=mydata,MAXIMUM PRINT:max:"%lf"```